# Byte array isn't stored inside object in Android?

Tags: android, file, object, storage

I have created an android app which should store a user profile in a local file on the device. Therefore I have an Object "Profile" with the attributes name, address and image. The attributes name and address are already stored in den profile. The attribute image is loaded via async task from a web server (which also works). Inside asynctask, I am calling a method to add the image to the profile:

```
// userProfile is an Object of type Profile
userProfile.setImage(byte_array_image);
// Writing it to file
FileOutputStream fos = activity.openFileOutput("profile", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
Log.e("Image:",""+userProfile.getImage()); // returns the byte array
os.writeObject(userProfile);
os.close();
fos.close();
```

Then I try to read it via openFileInput (the app is restarted). Might this be a problem that I restart the app? I can read all profile attributes except the image which is still null.

Andy idea how I might fix it and what causes the error? The writing for the image should overwrite the file profile.

Comment: Better way is to fetch image using Picasso or Glide and cache it.

Answer (score 0):

you can this method to get ByteArray from the file.

```
   var bytes: ByteArray = byteArrayOf()

    bytes = readAllBytes(context, file)

    if (bytes.isNotEmpty()) {

        /**
         * encode byteArray and store encrypted data in mFileTemp
         */
        val bos =
                BufferedOutputStream(
                        FileOutputStream(
                                mFileTemp
                        )
                )
        val encodedBytes =
                FileDownloader.encodeFile(yourKey, bytes)
        bos.write(encodedBytes)
        bos.flush()
        bos.close()
    }
```

> readAllBytes()

```
fun readAllBytes(context:Context, file:File) : ByteArray{

    var bytes: ByteArray = byteArrayOf()

    try {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            bytes = Files.readAllBytes(
                    Paths.get(
                            getRealPath(
                                    context,
                                    Uri.fromFile(file)
                            )
                    )
            )
        }else{
            bytes = readFile1(file)!!
        }
    }catch (e:Exception){
        Log.e(TAG, "readAllBytes exception : ${e.printStackTrace()}" )
    }


    return bytes
}
```